# Mass for mass could a prehensile tail hits harder than human's punch?

Tags: creature-design, fight, snake

Contestant 1: healthy adult male human weights 80kg with less than 5% body fat. Punching method based on principle of a lever.

Contestant 2: healthy adult serpentine species (limbless) with similar muscle mass as contestant 1. Works just like elephant trunk.

If we consider contestant 2's prehensile tail to work similarly to an elephant trunk, then mass for mass which one will hit much harder unarmed?

Comment: If the tailed contestant had limbs in order to use centrifugal forces they may have higher odds of winning a match of 'who hits hardest'

Comment: What does "_punching method based on principle of a lever_" actually mean? I hope you're not thinking of flailing arms around and using fists like a hammer, instead of a proper punch.

Comment: Does the tailed contestant have any way of anchoring its front end so that it may coil and uncoil or swipe its tail end to the end of delivering a kinetic impact? Otherwise the closest thing to a hit from such a creature would be a bodily collision.

Comment: Heh heh. Would YouTube lie to me?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tRFFMiD5AI

Answer (score 8):

I think the human would hit harder, because he would be able to use his legs, core and shoulders rotation to charge the fist, like any trained martial artist/boxeur can do. Just look at Bruce Lee's notorious [one inch punch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-inch_punch) to see what effect a proper preparation can give to a punch.

> In the television show MythBusters episode "The One Inch Punch", the technique was tested quantitatively using a force gauge. For comparison, it was matched against a conventional punch thrown with a full wind-up by Jamie Hyneman. The one-inch punch was delivered by Anthony Kelly, a martial arts expert and master instructor who had learned the technique from one of Bruce Lee's students. The conventional punch measured 325 pounds of force (148 kg) while the one-inch punch measured 153 pounds (69 kg).

The serpentine one, on the other hand, would not have any way to do so, therefore his punch would less effective.

Comment: Also, knuckles are quite hard, and humans are surprisingly good at using them as weapons. Tails don't really have the same sort of bone structure, meaning that a tail strike of any kind can't reasonably be compared to a punch.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Not counting animals with hardened club-tails or spiked thagomizers, naturally.

Comment: @IndigoFenix noted, but the OP didn't include important details like "_covered in huge deadly spikes_" ;-)

Comment: nonono, that _is_ a good point. A couple of strategic bone protrusions are the difference between a slap on the face and severe lacerations.

Comment: Sorry but anything related to Bruce Lee in a scientific discussion about martial arts is mostly myth, speculation and over hype.

Answer (score 6):

If we're comparing a punch delivered by a human  to a blow delivered by a serpentine being of the same weight, then it would depend upon the technique and speed of the serpentine being.

Since we're talking about a limbless serpentine creature, it's effectively a human-sized snake.

Now, if this big snake effectively flailed around with its head or tail, it would probably not be all that effective at delivering a blunt impact.  The part of its body delivering the blow would not weigh all that much, and unless anchored to a suitable object, there is a good chance that getting all that mass moving  would lead to its body slipping against the ground.  My gut feel as a martial artist is that a trained snake might be able to deliver such a blow 70-80% of the impact energy of that of a trained human.  It'd be the snake equivalent of a human delivering a slap.

However, snakes are adapted to delivering blows in another manner.  If a snake was to coil itself up, then launch its entire body at its target, almost its entire muscle mass would be involved in delivering the blow.  Its entire mass could be put behind the blow, and more muscle could be brought to bear on the task.  Venomous snake species have evolved specifically to do this, though with fangs-first rather than head first.

A human martial artist delivering a punch effectively has the extensor muscles of one arm and one leg behind a blow, plus a minor contribution from the muscles of the torso.  Research has shown that a trained human can deliver a punch carrying 1000J of energy, and can deliver it at around 15.6 m/s.  Solving for m in e=½mv² gives about 8 kg.  Since such a punch might be delivered over the space of 1.5 m, the acceleration can be calculated to be about 81.6 m/s².  This tallies with experimental measurements.

However, a snake launching a strike (or a head butt in a similar manoeuvre) would have *all* of its extensor muscles fully involved in the blow, and it has more muscle mass available to it than a human with the same muscle mass because it doesn't have useless limbs taking up part of its total muscle mass.

Many species of snake, both venomous and constrictors, have been recorded as having an acceleration when striking of around 190 m/s².  A snake weighing 100kg might be around 6 m long.  If it strikes with half of its body's length, making a 3 m strike, at this acceleration, its head might reach a speed of 34 m/s.   Assuming an impact weight of 1/10th of the snake's mass, allowing for the part of its body providing traction, and the fact that only its head is moving at maximum speed, we get an impact energy of 5780 J

5780J is nearly 6 times the impact energy that a trained human may generate.  In fact, unless the snake was evolved to deliver high energy impacts, it would likely scale down its strike speed to avoid self-injury.

However, in the case of a serpentine being evolved to maximise its impact energy rather than simply bite quickly, its blows would be devastating compared to those from a highly trained human.   Even Mike Tyson could only deliver 1600 J... and 5780 J is 3.6 times more impact energy than that.

Considering that the OP has said that this would be delivered by a *tail*, if it was delivered tip-first, unless the tail had a large,  solid weight on its tip like a club, or the impact was delivered by the side of the tail, thus increasing its contact area, its impact would be like a bullet, and there is a good chance that the target would be impaled by this tail, even if wearing ballistic armour.  5780 J is a lot more energy being delivered into a small area than that of many bullets fired  from pistols or even rifles.  Even if the impact was delivered over a large area of the tail, this impact would be a killer, likely breaking bones and/or rupturing internal organs.

Even if we halved the acceleration to 95 m/s² over 3m, and lowered the total mass to 80kg, for an impact mass of 8kg, we would still have an impact energy of 2280 J, more than twice the impact energy of a trained human's punch, probably delivered to a smaller area.

Comment: I like this answer, but it's hard to account for how good the snake is at "planting." In a punch, the impact travels back through the arm, shoulder, core, hips and legs, until it arrives at the planted back foot. All those joints do a good job of translating energy from bone to bone, which preserves power. Hit a heavy bag with a good stance, and then lift the rear leg and hit the heavy bag again - the difference is pretty stark. So I believe the snake could move faster - but what happens when it actually makes contact? Does a bunch of energy rebound into its own body, wasting it?

Comment: @codeMonkey All that matters is the velocity of the impact and the weight of the impactor.  The energy is delivered regardless of the fact that the object delivering it is braced against the ground or if it is entirely airborne.

Comment: "All that matters" is the IMPULSE. A rubber bullet and a lead bullet have the same kinetic energy, but one deforms on impact, spreading the energy out over more time, so it is less lethal. I'm questioning if the snake might "deform" more than a fist.

Comment: @codeMonkey If the energy is delivered over an impact area equivalent to a human fist, it's still 3.6 times the impact energy of Mike Tyson's best punch, and it's still likely to be crippling or fatal.

Comment: Agree with the peak acceleration number for snakes, but I find it unrealistic to expect that acceleration to be constant over the space of 3m. All the evidence I can find suggests even the fastest snake strikes are only a few m/s despite large peak accelerations - the 34m/s strike speed here seems many times too high.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie, that's because snakes heads are relatively fragile.  They need to be just fast enough to grab their prey.  This is a different scenario.

Comment: I'm really struggling with the physics here. To constantly accelerate half its body mass with sufficient force to achieve 19G of acceleration, friction between the other half of the body and the ground needs to supply the exact same force. F=ma in the front half, which equals F=u2mg in the back half - if a=19g, then the coefficient of friction needs to be 9.5, which is simply unheard of. The back half of the snake would need to be glued to the ground to accelerate constantly at such a rate, or else the back half just slips backwards.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Even if reduced from 190 to 95 m/s² over 3m, it's still over 2 kJ impact energy... which is still more than human.  Also, remember that the blow would be angled upwards.

Comment: worth noting large snakes are actually  slow and fairly weak, arge snakes are actually hard pressed ot move on land, the snake body plan just is not good for being big and fast, limbs allow for far more leverage for the muscles. Snake speed does not scale up.

Comment: Snakes are anything but weak, especially large snakes.  Besides, the OP didn't specifically say that the creature was a snake, just that it was 'serpentine'.

Answer (score 2):

**Thresher Shark vs. Keith Liddel**

[This](https://blog.joinfightcamp.com/training/the-ultimate-boxing-guide-to-punching-speed/) article tells:

> The record for the fastest punch is held by Keith Liddel who
> registered a punch at 45 miles per hour.

and [this](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2013/jul/10/thresher-sharks-tails-bullwhips-kill-stun-prey) article tells:

> Simon Oliver, a marine biologist at the Thresher Shark Research and
> Conservation Project in the Philippines, said the sharks' "tail slaps"
> reached a speed of 24 metres per second, or more than 50mph.

So Thresher Shark's tail slap speed (50mph) *in water* is more than Keith Liddel's punch speed (45mph) *in air*.

Comment: I'm not sure how comparable that is. The water offers resistance for the shark to "brace" against to deliver force. You don't have that in the air and as pointed out in other comments and answers, bracing against the ground is more difficult without limbs.

Comment: Speed is not the critical number for measuring how effective a blow is.  If it was, a bullwhip (top speed: faster than sound) would be considered more effective than a blackpowder musket (top speed: much slower).

Comment: Kinetic energy KE = ½ mv². Mass of Thresher Shark's tail > mass of punch.

Answer (score 1):

Muscles apply there force in contraction, whereas a punch is extension. Thus an exoskeleton provides significant advantage to delivering strikes. So any strikes by contestant #2 that do not accumulate energy greater then contestant #1 will by not be a solution to the question.

#### Can contestant #2 whip?

If contestant #2 can whip their tail, a pretty nasty blow could be delivered. A supersonic strike would do much more damage then a punch can. The cost however would be that there would likely be damage done to contestant #2 as well.

#### Can contestant #2 put body in tension?

That is can they do something like a finger flick? If they curl part of their body into a ring. Then use muscles on the outside of the ring to tension up then let go in a snap/flick. Depending on how much tension could be built up this could hit much harder then a punch.